# Java Web Start: Company Database

Tags: java, jdbc, java-web-start, jnlp

I have developed a Java database application that has been deployed to users via a web server. Now, all is good but it has been requested that some of our external clients would also like access to the software. Is there any way that I can make the application work for these clients? The application has been put on another web sever that is accessible for external users and also has visibility to our SQL server but the application is not working, it will load in the browser but users cannot login to the system which works by database authentication. Am I missing something simple here or is this something that can't be done. I would imagine the latter since I think the web start application downloads to users machines which would explain why you can only login when a VPN connection is active.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be a firewall issue.  What errors are you getting

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely your firewall blocks the connections to your database when they are initiated from the outside. This is a good thing because you generally don't want to expose a database to the Internet.

One hacky way to do it would be to implement some kind of *JDBC over HTTP* to tunnel the database requests. Basically you'd use a JDBC driver that redirects the SQL requests to a web server.

A better way would be to refactor your code (I presume that would be a lot of work though...)
If you manage to abstract the data access layer, you can replace it by something more suitable for a web access, for instance a Web Service.

Finally a drastic option is to transform your client/database application into a webapp.